# Return Confirm() in php

Tags: javascript, php

In a php tag, I wrote this:

```
<?php echo '
<form method = "post" onsubmit="return confirm('test');">
</form>
'; ?>
```

I receive a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'test' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Might anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what is the `\ ` at `onsubmit=\"...` for? And the error you get is a php (not js) error, isn't it? Please show the surrounding code and the line the error is at.

Comment: Sorry, i've removed the backslash. And yes its a php error.

Comment: I've seen the article, but its somewhat general and I can't seem to zero in on what the precise solution might be here.

Comment: Can you post the PHP code from your page here so we can help?

Comment: Edited my question to reflect the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

' quatation will not work in string since you started string with single quatation try to escape with \
like \'

try this

```
<?php echo '
<form method = "post" onsubmit="return confirm(\'test\');">
</form>
'; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Ismail, how and where should I put the slashes?

Comment: try this

<?php echo '
<form method = "post" onsubmit="return confirm(\'test\');">
</form>
'; ?>

Comment: That's brilliant. It solved my problem.

Comment: happy to help ;)